# SQL Insert from a source table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not sure how to google this...  Here's what I need to do but I'm not sure how to do the insert and generate the NewID at the same time.

I have 2 tables one (pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyId) is empty and only has 3 fields candidateid, vacancyId and its primary key, all 3 fields are guids.   I need to get the data from a second table that has the matching fields but I also have to create and insert a guid at the same time.  The source table (pcx_vacancyassociationExtensionBase) has 2 matching fields.  Finally I will use NewID() to generate the new guid for the primary key.

Comment: Ok. And what is your question?

Comment: Reference to `NEWID()` suggests (to me) that this is a question about SQL Server. If that's so, please add a suitable tag for it. If, instead, it's for a different database, please add a tag for that. The `sql` tag by itself is for the standard SQL language, which no database system I'm aware of actually fully implements - so it's helpful to include the database system when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can insert directly from one table to another via an `insert into ... select ...` query:

```
insert into pcx_candidate_to_pcx_vacancyId (id, candidateid, vacancyId)
select NewID(), candidateid, vacancyId
from pcx_vacancyassociationExtensionBase
```